# Refreshing MonoDevelop add-in repositories giving "Could not get information from repository - 404"

Tags: add-in, monodevelop

I just installed MonoDevelop, but I cannot refresh the add-in repositories (see picture)

[image: Error]

Version info:

```
MonoDevelop 2.8.5.1

Installation UUID: 843726be-82cf-4694-86fc-4d3d9f7bf912

Runtime:

    Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.239

    GTK 2.16.6

    GTK# (2.12.0.0)

Mono for Android not installed

No build info

Operating System:

    Windows 6.1.7601.65536 (64-bit)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                           4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll

MonoDevelop                        2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\MonoDevelop.exe

MonoDevelop.Ide                    2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\MonoDevelop.Ide.dll

MonoDevelop.Core                   2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\MonoDevelop.Core.dll

Mono.Addins                        0.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.Addins.dll

System                             4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll

System.Xml.Linq                    4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll

System.Core                        4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll

System.Xml                         4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll

gtk-sharp                          2.12.0.0 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\gtk-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\gtk-sharp.dll

glib-sharp                         2.12.0.0 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\glib-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\glib-sharp.dll

atk-sharp                          2.12.0.0 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\atk-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\atk-sharp.dll

gdk-sharp                          2.12.0.0 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\gdk-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\gdk-sharp.dll

Mono.Posix                         2.0.0.0  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Mono.Posix\2.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756\Mono.Posix.dll

Mono.TextEditor                    1.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.TextEditor.dll

Mono.Cairo                         2.0.0.0  C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Mono.Cairo\2.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756\Mono.Cairo.dll

Mono.Addins.Setup                  0.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.Addins.Setup.dll

System.Configuration               4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll

Xamarin.Ide                        1.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Xamarin.Ide.dll

Mono.Posix                         4.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Mono.Posix.dll

Mono.AndroidTools                  0.9.3.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\Mono.AndroidTools.dll

MonoDevelop.MonoDroid              4.0.0.24 C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.dll

WindowsPlatform                    2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\WindowsPlatform.dll

Mono.Cecil                         0.9.4.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.Cecil.dll

MonoDevelop.Debugger               2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.Debugger\MonoDevelop.Debugger.dll

MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2          2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2.dll

MonoDevelop.VersionControl         2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.dll

System.Drawing                     4.0.0.0  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll

MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport        2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport\MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.dll

MonoDevelop.Deployment             2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.Deployment\MonoDevelop.Deployment.dll

MonoDevelop.XmlEditor              2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.XmlEditor\MonoDevelop.XmlEditor.dll

MonoDevelop.AspNet                 2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.AspNet\MonoDevelop.AspNet.dll

MonoDevelop.Moonlight              2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.Moonlight\MonoDevelop.Moonlight.dll

pango-sharp                        2.12.0.0 C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\pango-sharp\2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f\pango-sharp.dll

Mono.Debugging                     0.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.Debugging.dll

MonoDevelop.NUnit                  2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\NUnit\MonoDevelop.NUnit.dll

nunit.core                         2.4.8.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\NUnit\nunit.core.dll

nunit.core.interfaces              2.4.8.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\NUnit\nunit.core.interfaces.dll

nunit.framework                    2.4.8.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\NUnit\nunit.framework.dll

nunit.util                         2.4.8.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\NUnit\nunit.util.dll

libstetic                          0.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.GtkCore\libstetic.dll

libsteticui                        0.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.GtkCore\libsteticui.dll

MonoDevelop.GtkCore                2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.GtkCore\MonoDevelop.GtkCore.dll

Xamarin.Ide.Windows                1.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Xamarin.Ide.Windows.dll

monodoc                            1.0.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\monodoc.dll

Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell 1.1.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack       1.1.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll

MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit           2.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\AddIns\MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit\MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit.dll

Mono.Addins.Gui                    0.6.0.0  C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop\bin\Mono.Addins.Gui.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the last revision part of the repository url fixes the problem:

```
http://addins..../2.8.5.1 > http://addins..../2.8.5
```